# mvc3 razor syntax problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to give id to div in a loop and i want to use that code

```
<div id="img_@Model.PG_ID" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #cccccc;">
```

but the rendered html is img_@Model.PG_ID and not img_xyz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<div id="img_@(Model.PG_ID)" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #cccccc;">
```